# Best way to process ajax request in django view

Tags: python, django

Let's assume, in web page i have ajax request, which sends different parameters into django view (for example, via POST).

For example:

- products (list of integers)
- products_params (list of strings)

Both list must have the same length.

What is the best way to ensure, that data is correct?

Here is the pseudocode for processing this request.

```
if 'products' and 'products_params' in request.POST and request.is_ajax():
    try:
        products = [int(p) for p in request.POST['products']]
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    products_params = request.POST['products_params']
    if len(products) != len(products_params):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    # ok, data is correct, now we can process it
```

Is there a better way to do this? How to be sure, that we do not get unexpected exception because of invalid data given to our view?

P.S. It is ajax-only processing. No forms are shown to user.

Comment: is request.is_ajax() not request.is_ajax

Comment: What about using forms?

Comment: This is ajax-only processing in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
    products = [int(p) for p in request.POST['products'] if str(p).isdigit()]
```

or

```
    products = [int(p) for p in request.POST['products'] if unicode(p).isnumeric()]
```

I recommend the first one, because if you use **ñ** for example `unicode` will throw an error.

And your code can look like this:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    products = [int(p) for p in request.POST.get('products',[]) if str(p).isdigit()]
    products_params = request.POST.get('products_params', [])
    if (not (products and products_params)) or (len(products) != len(products_params)):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Comment: It does not answer the whole question.

Comment: I think this answers the  **How to be sure, that we do not get unexpected exception because of invalid data given to our view?**

Comment: Yes, it does. But what about other parts of validation?

Comment: Ok, this seems suitable for me.